# Server sent Message to the client but the Message is not display in the Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, socket.io

i use nodejs as a Server. Usinf socket.io i want to refresh my Chart, when new Data are insert in the Database Table.

That is the Server Code to add Data in the Table. After add Data in the Database, i send a message to the client to update my Chart.

```
app.post('/usersacces/add', function (req,res) {
    var response = [];

    if (typeof req.body.alias!== 'undefined' &&typeof req.body.nom!== 'undefined'   ) {
        var alias = req.body.alias, nom = req.body.nom;

        connection.query('INSERT INTO administration_users_niveaux_acces (alias, nom) VALUES (?, ?)',
            [alias, nom],
            function(err, result) {
                if (!err){

                    if (result.affectedRows != 0) {
                        response.push({'result' : 'success'});

                    } else {
                        response.push({'msg' : 'No Result Found'});
                    }
          // When a client connects, we note it in the console
          io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
              socket.emit('message', 'You are connected!');
              console.log('message '+ 'You are connected!');
          });
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
                } else {
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                }
            });

    } else {
        response.push({'result' : 'error', 'msg' : 'Please fill required details'});
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
 });
```

That is the Client, that should receive a Message and update the Chart. But when add new Data in the Database on button Click, the Chart are not update and the message sent for the Server are not display in the Console. It only display when i load the Page.

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
          var databa = [];
          $.ajax({
                  url: '/usersacces'
              })
              .done(function(data) {
                  for (var i = 0, len = data[0].items.length; i < len; i++) {
                      var e1 = data[0].items[i].id;
                      databa.push(e1);
                  }
                  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = databa;
                          myChart.update();
              }).always(function() {
                  console.log(1);

              });

        console.log('The server has a message for you: ' + message);
    });
```

Comment: So you don't receive the message when you do console.log('The server has a message for you: ' message);  ?? I don't see where you are emitting a message to the client with the new data?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your socket only emits message when a user connected but never create any other "event" for socket to listen. Therefore the logic of your code is a little bit confusing. Your front-end makes http request when it receives a message. However the socket server is created when the backend receives an http request. Your issue is caused by the logic.

When I use socket.io in node.js, I always claim the socket when define my server like this:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log("A user connected");
        // Trigger an event when receive a message
        socket.on("event1", (data, callback) => {
        });

        // Emit a message when server did something
        // I used amqp to communicate within backend server
        // You can simply pass socket to wherever you want to emit the message
        amqpReceiver("event2" + socket.id, (msg) => {
            socket.emit("event2", msg);
        });

        // This is an emit example for you
        // Having a service claimed here makes your code hard to read
        // You can find a lot of ways to pass your socket
        app.post("/usersacces/add", function (req, res) {
            // Emit message during service process
            socket.emit("event3", msg);
        });
    });
```

Then at front-end I listen on the event like this:

```
socket.on("event3", (message) => {
    console.log(message);
})

// Make request outside of socket.on callback
 $.ajax({ url: "/usersacces" })
  .done(function(data) {})
```

The logic of my code is:

Set up socket connection first and keep front-end and back-end listening. Then trigger emit event whenever needed.

Hope it is helpful.